# Ubuntu server 18.04.05 LTS apt update / install snmp snmp-mibs-downloader error

Tags: apt, server, updates, snmp

After typing the command `sudo apt update` I get reply:

```
Err:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and after typing the command `sudo apt install snmp snmp-mibs-downloader` I get reply:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package snmp-mibs-downloader is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'snmp-mibs-downloader' has no installation candidate
```

What are these errors and how can I fix them?

Comment: Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com' That is the error and it means that for what ever reason that site is down right now. Try another site or try again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this command fixes the problem:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

**eth0** - name of the network interface

Answer (score 0):

The repositories in Poland appear to be down right now. Temporary failure resolving 'pl.archive.ubuntu.com' That is the error and it means that for what ever reason that site is down right now. Try another site or try again later. You could edit the sources list or wait an hour and try again.

The source list /etc/apt/sources. list and the files contained in /etc/apt/sources. list. d/ are designed to support any number of active sources and a variety of source media.

You could try the UK or US site by changing the pl to uk for example.

Comment: After typing one of the addresses in the browser, fox example: http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease website is available. Should it be that way?

Comment: That tells you the DNS record and the site exist but not that you can retrieve from it. This happens now and then it may be for maintenance.

Comment: Problem is the same with UK and US site.